# Gradle project sync failed - Android Studio 0.8.14

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

So I'm trying out Android Studio (new to android programming but not programming in general) and I'm having a bit of a struggle. Right off the bat after creating my new project, I receive the error message "Gradle Project Sync Failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly."

This message also includes this Gradle Sync message:

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read below process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I've read article after article (most on SO, Google Code, etc.) pertaining to this issue, however nothing seems to have worked so far (I'm guessing because almost every article was referencing a different Android Studio version).

Has anyone encountered this issue using my version (or one that's close to it)?

I'm running 64-bit Windows 7 and have installed the latest 64-bit JDK release (as of the date of this post). Please let me know if you need any other information regarding my new project or setup.

Thank you all.

Comment: How much free ram do you have? try closing all other apps and sync again.

Comment: Try setting up the project with java 7 jdk instead of java 8.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the entire folder located at `C:\Users\<username>\gradle\wrapper\dists` and when I restarted Android Studio, it downloaded the entire thing again and it worked.

I did try the other suggestion here which didn't work for me but give it a shot too:

[Gradle project sync failed - Android Studio 0.8.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774312/gradle-project-sync-failed-android-studio-0-8-14)

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem and found here when searched in Google. But Saurabh's answer didn't work for me. I found another answer online and it works.

How to fix this error: You have to create this as an environment variable: Variable: `_JAVA_OPTIONS` Value: -Xmx512M

under windows cmd

```
setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Xmx512M
```

under linux terminal

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512M
```

ref link:
https://programmierung-dresden.de/category/android/

Hope it helps other people who got the same issue.